# jQuery Selectors

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to take this from view source, i.e.:

```
<a  href="javascript:validateCB();"><img src="wwv_flow_file_mgr.get_file?p_security_group_id=1343380920146312332&p_flow_id=222&p_fname=submit_btn.gif" alt="Submit Details" border="0"  />
```

into jQuery selector format

```
var $templateButtons = $('img[src^="wwv_flow_file_mgr"]').parent('a');
```

But this doesn't seem to be correct.

How can I translate the above view source code into jQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with the attribute selector: `$('img[src^="wwv_flow_file_mgr"]')`

You're experiencing a [known bug](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4244) in jQuery v1.3.2 - jQuery is trying to interpret the image path using its absolute URL, which means the URL it's comparing actually starts with "`http://...`"

You can temporarily get around this using `*=` (which looks for an attribute value that contains the text "wwv_flow_file_mgr" instead of starting with it):

```
var $templateButtons = $('img[src*="wwv_flow_file_mgr"]').parent('a');
```

Comment: Thanks for the details regarding this bug. I didn't know it existed.

Comment: Hi, tried this but I am getting the following error, i.e. "attr(...)" is null or not an object.

Unsure if it's from this code snippet:

      $templateButtons.attr('data-submitval', function(){  
         return $(this).attr('onclick').toString().split('\n')[2];  
      });  
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is very odd, it doesn't work with the selector you have, although, I think it should.

However, while not very clean, it does work using a filter as shown below.

```
var $templateButtons = $("img")
                       .filter(function(){
                             return $(this).attr('src')
                                    .indexOf('wwv_flow_file_mgr')==0;
                       }).parent('a');
```