# How to get an image by its source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find

How can I write client javascript to get an image by its source ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752857/jquery-select-img-with-src and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835378/jquery-how-to-find-an-image-by-its-src and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007860/jquery-selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An image that is on the page?

You can do this with jQuery:

```
<body>
    <!-- your content including the image -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var myimg = $('img[src="/some/path/to/img.jpg"]');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This uses the [`tag-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/tag-selector/) along with the [`attribute-equals-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get `img` elements where the `src` matches the source you want.

Comment: Though I suggest putting the script tags in the `<head>` section, not the body, just to adhere to standards and keep things tidy. `$(function() { //stuff here });` ensures that the script isn't run until the DOM is ready, so putting it in the `<head>` section won't be a problem.

Comment: @Chevex: Yes, the `$(function() {});` does ensure DOM ready, but I'm not sure which standard you're referring to.

Comment: W3C recommends placing these in the `<head>` section simply for readability. Especially references to external scripts like the JQuery CDN.

Comment: @Chevex: I can't find that recommendation. Could you please give me a pointer? Placing `<script>` tags in the `<body>` does adhere to the standard. From [HTML 4.0.1, 18.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) *"This element may appear any number of times in the HEAD or BODY of an HTML document."* I skimmed for further recommendations, but couldn't find any, but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery.

$("img[src='imageurl.jpg']")